# Error in Angular: earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: eqfeed_callback is not defined at earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1:1

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, google-maps

I'm trying to replicate the **Importing Data into Maps** ([Importing Data into Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data#maps_earthquake_markers-typescript)) example to my angular project but I get the following error in console:

```
earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: eqfeed_callback is not defined
    at earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1:1
```

##### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'map';

  ngOnInit() {

    let map: google.maps.Map;
    
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
    });
    
    loader.load().then(() => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
        mapTypeId: "terrain",
      });

      // map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');

      // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
      const script = document.createElement("script");

      // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
      // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
      script.src =
        "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

      const eqfeed_callback = function (results: any) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          const coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);
      
          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
          });
          // place marker in map
          marker.setMap(map)
        }
      };    
    });   
  }
}
```

##### app.component.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

##### app.component.css

```
 #map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

##### Installed Packages

This is the googlemaps package that I installed in my project.

```
npm install @googlemaps/js-api-loader

npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

##### My Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: win32 x64
```

##### What my code shows

Just appear the map but without markers.

##### What I hope will appear

According to the Google Maps documentation at the following link: [Importing Data into Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data#maps_earthquake_markers-typescript)

Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: Hello, I've removed the API key from the post and replaced it with "YOUR_API_KEY" for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that your map appears but the markers don't.

Just like you said, what you want to happen is for the markers to show.

What I did is I tried to replicate your code in codesandbox and found out two main errors:

1. `'map' is defined but never used. (@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)`
2. `'eqfeed_callback' is assigned a value but never used. (@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)`

Solutions:

**Error #1:** app.component.ts had an unused variable of `map` and it looks like this in your code:

```
ngOnInit() {

let map: google.maps.Map;

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
});

loader.load().then(() => {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
```

the `map` variable inside the `loader.load().then` is the one you used and the one on top is the unused which caused error #1. I just removed it and it removed the error on the console.

**Error #2:** your code had a variable `eqfeed_callback` that stored a function but was not called. I compared your code to the sample you gave [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data#maps_earthquake_markers-typescript) and confirmed that there was a callback on the code there.

As I am not very familiar to typescript and angular I tried experimenting on the code and made it work by making the end part of your code look like this:

```
const eqfeed_callback = function (results: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      const coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
      // place marker in map
      marker.setMap(map);
    }
  };
  window.eqfeed_callback = eqfeed_callback;
});
```

}
}

I just inserted `window.eqfeed_callback = eqfeed_callback` and it made the error disappear and at the same time show the markers on the map.

Here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sound-p8qtrc

Just use your own API key.

I hope this helps.